# Use github secret in Ansible play without making it clear text

Tags: text, ansible, github-actions, masking, github-secret

How can I use github secrets in Ansible play without them being visible in clear text?

Currently, I invoke ansible play using the “oracle linux automation manager” API from github actions.

While calling ansible job using API we pass github secret as Extravars to ansible play like here: `--extra-vars "DBpass=${{ secrets.myteamtoken }}"` .

However, this secret is visible in clear text in Ansible logs when I invoke a Mongo database command like the below:

```
docker exec -ti {{ container_name }} mongoimport --port {{ DBport }} --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u '{{ DBuser }}' -p '{{ DBpass }}' --jsonArray --type=json --file audit/scripts/json/{{ item | basename }} --legacy
```

**Note:** github runner and ansible agents are on different hosts.

Can you please suggest how I can make sure that the DBpass from github is not visible when used in Ansible-play?

Saving this and many such credentials in Oracle Linux Automation Manager / Ansible Vault would be an overhead that I wish to avoid. Changing passwords in github as well as Ansible would be a trivial/redundant effort.

Comment: Set [`no_logs: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html#protecting-sensitive-data-with-no-log) on the relevant tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will help, but to address the passwords issue in logs

> However, this secret is visible in clear text in Ansible logs […]

Add `no_log: true` to tasks where the passwords are in use. (for example tasks with `DBpass` in your case.) See example and explanation in [official FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-keep-secret-data-in-my-playbook).
Also consider `diff: no` to those tasks.